# ¿Por que mi IFormFile no recibe nada? ASP.NET MVC 5 (Net. Framework) ClosedXML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un problema con recibir un archivo Excel, estoy utilizando closedXML, cuando mando desde la vista el archivo en el controllador se recibe como null, lo probe en ASP .NET Core y funciona, pero no en el ASP.NET MVC 5 (Net. Framework)... Les dejo parte del codigo:

HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportarPersonasDesdeExcel(IFormFile excel)
    {

var workbook = new XLWorkbook(excel.OpenReadStream());

var hoja = workbook.Worksheet(1);

var primeraFilaUsada = hoja.FirstRowUsed().RangeAddress.FirstAddress.RowNumber;
var ultimaFilaUsada = hoja.LastRowUsed().RangeAddress.FirstAddress.RowNumber;

var personas = new List<Personas>();

for (int i = primeraFilaUsada + 1; i <= ultimaFilaUsada; i++)
{
    var fila = hoja.Row(i);
    var persona = new Personas();

    persona.nombre = fila.Cell(1).GetString();
    persona.fechaNac = fila.Cell(3).GetDateTime();
    persona.salario = fila.Cell(2).GetValue<double>();

    personas.Add(persona);

}

db.PersonasSet.AddRange(personas);
db.SaveChanges();

return View("Index");
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("ImportarPersonasDesdeExcel", "Home")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <p class="card-title">Subir archivo excel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="file" name="excel" id="excel" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

'

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]